# Find the Relation between $a,b,c$

Tags: geometry, contest-math, circles, tangent-line

[image]

In the figure shown find the relation between $a,b,c$.

My try:
When two circles of radii $r_1,r_2$ touch externally, the length of their direct common tangent is $2\sqrt{r_1r_2}$
Let the radius of the bigger circle is $r_1$ and that of smaller one is $r_2$. We have:

$AM=a$

$MK=2\sqrt{r_1r_2}$

By Pythagoras theorem we get:
$$AK^2+4r_1^2=(a+b+c)^2$$

Also by secant tangent theorem we have:
$$AK^2=AC \times AD$$ So we get:
$$AK^2=(a+b)(a+c)$$
So we get:
$$4r_1^2=b^2+c^2+ab+bc+ca$$

Any hint from here?

Comment: $AK^2$ should be $(a+b)(a+b+c)$.

Answer (score 1):

If you let angle KAD = 2p, then sin(2p) = 2(r1)/(a+b+c) from triangle AKD

from a circle theorem angle KCD is a right angle and angle CKD=2p, so c=2(r1)sin(2p)
and so c=4r(1)^2/(a+b+c)

then perhaps you can use what you did to eliminate r1

...after trying it, it leads to an inconsistency, there might be a mistake in your AK^2 line, second bracket should be (a+b+c), then it's the same result...would then recommend using triangle AB(O2), where O2 is the centre of circle 2, tan(p)=(r2)/a and cos(2p)=AK/(a+b+c) from triangle AKD and then use trig identities to try and eliminate unwanted letters.

...further results:
$$4r_1^2=c(a+b+c) $$

$$AK = \sqrt{(a+b)(a+b+c)}$$

$$sin(2p)=\sqrt{\frac{c}{a+b+c}}$$

$$cos(2p)=\sqrt{\frac{a+b}{a+b+c}}$$

$$tan(2p)=\sqrt{\frac{c}{a+b}}$$

so perhaps they can be related using inverse trig functions, all equalling 2p and each other.

Comment: Any use to you?